# DOMAttr's value attribute is confusing?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I've been working with DOMDocument and all its related classes, but some things are still unclear to me.

For example, $domattr->value returns

```
http://bla.com/?bla=test&bla2=test
```

when it should return

```
http://bla.com/?bla=test&amp;bla2=test
```

(because this is what the attribute nodes text node literally contains)

So here are my questions:

1) Why is it converting the ampersand: What's the logic behind it from DOMAttr's point of view?

2) How can I work with DOMNodes so that I get the real values?

3) What are some best practices when dealing with this kind of stuff? I want to have consistent and predictable code and behavior, but it can be confusing when I don't get what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of writing `&amp;` instead of `&` is because the `&` character has special meaning in HTML source code. When the browser parses the HTML source code into the DOM tree, it transforms the HTML entities (`&nbsp;`, `&bull;`, etc.) into their corresponding characters. There is no need to preserve the HTML entities inside the DOM tree - the browsers don't do that.

Comment: So then DOMNode::$nodeValue, DOMNode::$textContent and DOMAttr::$value all behave the same way regarding html special chars?

Comment: @x74x61 Yes. I'm not sure where this is defined in the HTML standard, but I did a quick test across browsers and the entities are replaced in all of them.

Comment: AH, ok. I think I'm getting it now. So methods like DOMNode::saveHTML() make it all html entities again, right? Thanks man, cleared up almost everything.

Comment: @x74x61 Hm, I don't know (I don't work with PHP DOM). Rather test it if you can...

Comment: saveHTML() returns string with html representation of dom (or part of it), so I'm pretty sure it does. I'll test it. edit: I mean DOMDocument::saveHTML()